# Parse.com data design

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, database, nosql

I have a question regarding how I should set up a database in Parse.com to have scalable queries. Below, is a picture of a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

[image: First Approach]

So, as you can see with this idea, there is a user, that can create a `ChatMessage` or a `MainMessage`. The `MainMessage` also can have `Comments` posted to it. However, in a "feed" I will want to display both `ChatMessages` and `MainMessages` by `dateCreated` and I don't think that it will be an efficient query to get both `ChatMessages` and then `MainMessages`, and then sort.

To simplify, I have this...

[image: Second Approach]

As you can see, I made both `ChatMessage` and `MainMessage` from the first approach into a single `Message` with all of the attributes for both `ChatMessage` and `MainMessage` with the additional `type` attribute to distinguish between the two. Is it okay that in the new `Message` that will have multiple unused attributes based on type? Is that inefficient in Parse.com? Hypothetically, if `MainMessage` had way more (say 10) attributes than `ChatMessage` would this still be okay? I believe the second approach is better because I can simplify the query for the "feed". However, if there is anybody with anything to say on how I should be setting up the database, any comments are greatly appreciated. Thanks.